# ls | grep with variable as regex

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script to automate a few tasks.  One of the things I have to do is search for a pattern among filenames in a directory, then loop through the results.

When I run this script:

```
data=$(ls $A_PATH_VAR/*.ext | grep -o '201601[0-9]\{2\}\|201602[0-9]\{2\}')
echo $data
```

I get the expected result - a list of all the matches that were found among the filenames in `$A_PATH_VAR/` with the extension `.ext`.  However, when I store said pattern in a variable and then use it, like this:

```
startmo=201601
endmo=201602

mo=$((startmo+1))
grepstr="'$startmo[0-9]\{2\}"

while [ $mo -le $endmo ]
do
  grepstr="$grepstr\|$mo[0-9]\{2\}"
  mo=$((mo+1))
done

grepstr="$grepstr'"

echo $grepstr # correct

data=$(ls $A_PATH_VAR/*.ext | grep -o $grepstr)
echo $data
```

The pattern in `$grepstr` is correctly echoed - that is, it contains the value `'201601[0-9]\{2\}\|201602[0-9]\{2\}'`, but `$data` is empty.  Why is this?

---

My solution:

```
mo=$((startmo+1))
grepstr="($startmo[0-9][0-9]"

while [ $mo -le $endmo ]
do
  grepstr="$grepstr|$mo[0-9][0-9]"
  mo=$((mo+1))
done

grepstr="$grepstr)"

files=$(ls $A_PATH_VAR/*.ext)

setopt shwordsplit

for file in $files
do
  if [[ $file =~ $grepstr ]]
  then
    date=$BASH_REMATCH
  fi

  ...
done
```

Comment: `pattern="'pattern'"` should be `pattern='pattern'` and you need to quote your variables every where

Comment: You shouldn't be grepping `ls` output to begin with. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...as for understanding why you can't mix literal and syntactic quotes, a good place to start is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: What's your goal, btw? To find files with a substring in their names? `files=( *"$string"* )` will suffice. If it's a more complex pattern, then an extglob will suffice; see relevant subset of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern.

Comment: ...whereas if you want to non-recursively find directory entries that actually match a regex, and have GNU find, use `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex "$regex"`. Capturing output from `find` into a shell array is tricky to do in a way that covers all the corner cases and requires `-print0`, whereas capturing output from `ls` in a way that covers all the corner cases is literally impossible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The path I'm searching through contains files with filenames that are made up of dates and other information.  I want to examine only those files with certain extensions that contain dates within a date range only known at runtime, and obtain only the date part of the filename.  The only thing I'm hung up on is $pattern - I use a variable in the pathname to ls and that works fine (I can test this in a script), but grep doesn't seem to like the variable I provide it.

Comment: I believe my answer should adequately explain why the variable won't work as-given. If it doesn't, please ask an explicit follow-up question.

Comment: BTW, if you have a filename already in a bash variable and want to use a regex to extract a portion of it, `[[ $name =~ $regex_var ]]` will leave the match groups within the regex stored in `regex_var` is members in the array named `BASH_REMATCH`. Which is to say that there are very good tools for the purpose built into the language, and you should be using them instead of hacking around with `ls` and `grep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the below, I'm ignoring that your input source is `ls`, beyond this opening note that [`ls` should not be used in this manner](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [`find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (which, in GNU-extended forms, contains a `-regex` operator) should be considered instead.

---

In:

```
pattern="'pattern'"
grep $pattern
```

...the double quotes (`"`) are *syntactic* -- they're consumed by the shell during its parsing phase, whereas the single quotes, inside of them, are *literal* -- the outer, syntactic quotes specified that everything inside them is to be considered a part of the string (except where the rules for parsing double-quoted content differ).

Thus, when you run `grep $pattern`, the following happens:

- The contents of `$pattern` are broken into words on any characters within IFS. By default, IFS contains only whitespace; however, if you had `IFS=a`, then this would be broken into a word `"pa` and a word `ttern"`
- Each of these words is expanded as a glob. Thus, if your `pattern` had contained `"hello * world"`, and you had a default value of IFS parsing on whitespace, we would have broken into the words `"hello`, `*`, and `world"` -- and the `*` would then be replaced with a list of files in the current directory.

Obviously, you don't want this. Thus, use only syntactic quotes if your goal is to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion:

```
pattern="pattern"
grep "$pattern"
```

---

BTW, if I had this task, I might write it as follows [to avoid needing to hand-build a regex for each possible date range]:

```
startmo=201601
endmo=201705
currmo=$startmo

# this requires GNU date
# on MacOS, you can install this via macports and invoke it as gdate
next_month() {
  date -d "+1 month ${1:0:4}-${1:4:2}-15" +%Y%m
}

while [[ $currmo <= $endmo ]]; do
  currmo=$(next_month "$currmo")
  files=( *"$currmo"* )
  [[ -e $files ]] || { echo "No files found for month $currmo" >&2; continue; }
  printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
done
```

Comment: I think you should include your comment on using the rematch operator in this answer.  I was able to accomplish what I was out to do by avoiding grep and using that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure that your question described what you were out to do in sufficient detail to allow a really good answer along those lines. If you included the literal pattern, as opposed to just a `"pattern"` placeholder, an example of a filename matching that pattern, and an example of your desired output, it'd be easier to do so.

Comment: @NmdMystery, ...I've added my own solution, which actually doesn't involve regular expressions at all. It might be a little less than ideally efficient if you were scanning a really huge directory, but has some advantages, such as being able to cross year boundaries cleanly.

Comment: To be more specific: there's one file for each day in the month, so just searching for the month in the filename won't do the job - I need to extract the format YYYYMMDD from the filename, and only those eight characters.  I could just hard code the days in the month, etc, but in the future there could be a situation where that might not work.

Comment: Which eight characters? AFAICT you didn't actually address the "example of a filename matching that pattern" or "example of your desired output" request.

Comment: I posted the solution that I used, feel free to give it a critique if you want.

Comment: I still can't evaluate that solution without knowing the problem that it's intended to solve. What do the *actual* filenames look like? A `grep -o` pattern tells me what content is somewhere inside them, but "somewhere inside them" isn't very specific.

Comment: okay, that said, the main critique is that it's still using `ls`. That's going to fall down very badly on unexpected filenames (names with whitespace, names with glob characters, etc). Replace `files=$(ls $A_PATH_VAR/*.ext)` with `files=( "$A_PATH_VAR"/*.ext )`, and `for file in $files` with `for file in "${files[@]}"`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really divulge the problem in concrete terms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114893/discussion-between-nmdmystery-and-charles-duffy).